# Parse doc and xls files in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails application, I need to upload some doc/xls files and parse its structure and get information. How can I get data from *.doc or *.xls in maybe xml format or anything else that I can read and parse?

Comment: Take a look at the [Yomu](https://github.com/Erol/yomu) gem.

Comment: @NickVeys Thanks. But how I can open dc file in xml? can you give some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse different types of spreadsheets using the [Roo](https://github.com/Empact/roo) gem. It supports:

- OpenOffice
- Excel
- Google spreadsheets
- Excelx
- LibreOffice
- CSV

From my experience it has some issues with parsing .xls files, however parsing .xlsx files is good.

As for .doc files, you may try using [msworddoc-extractor](https://github.com/dayflower/msworddoc-extractor) gem or try one of the solutions proposed [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1296459).

**Update:** working with *.docx files - [docx](https://github.com/chrahunt/docx) and [docx-html](https://github.com/mportiz08/docx-html)

Comment: And what about .doc files?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the Nokogiri gem? http://nokogiri.org/

Very useful for xml parsing

Comment: it's good but not for my issue. I need easy way for parse xml structure for big files

Answer (score 0):

The spreadsheet gem is nice for excel and csv files. 
https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet

Comment: I was use it and get this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915887/ruby-roo-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file-spreadsheet-note